# How to update a NSManagedObject

Tags: edit, nsmanagedobject

I have an NSMutableArray with a few NSManagedObjects in it which I fetched from my managedObjectContext.
How can I edit the managedObjects and write replace the old object with the new one?

I'm taking the object like this from the array:

```
NSManagedObject *managedObject = [_dataArray objectAtIndex:indexToTest];
[managedObject setValue:@"sucessfully updated!" forKey:@"hint"];
```

My problem is, how can I update the managedObject in the managedObjectContext?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

- Get the NSManagedObject and set value

> NSManagedObject *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
>     [object setValue: self.urlField.text forKey:@"url"];

- then get NSManagedObjectContext object and save it

> NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
>   NSError *error = nil;
>       if (![context save:&error]) {}